# Звездчатый или звёздчатый

Tags: орфография, е-или-ё

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно, «звездчатый» или «звёздчатый»?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) В орфоэпическом словаре Резниченко (2010 год) даются две форы: **звЕздчатый и звездчАтый, произношение звёздчатый устарело.**

В словаре Аванесова (1987) то же самое: звЕздчатый и звездчАтый (буква Ё в это словаре обозначается ― звёздный).

2) В то же время  в толковом словаре на Грамоте.ру указана форма ***звёздчатый.***

(Большой толковый словарь русского языка. Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов. Публикуется в авторской редакции **2014 года)**. **ЗВЁЗДЧАТЫЙ,**  1. Имеющий форму звезды. 2. Искристый, сверкающий.

В текстах **звЁздчатый** также встречается:

Самый крупный огранённый звёздчатый сапфир сейчас называется «Одинокая звезда» и весит 9719, 5 карата. [Александр Орлов. Сапфир Александра Македонского // «Зеркало мира», 2012]

Википедия: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Звёздчатый_многогранник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)